Is fwrite() atomic when applied to multiple FILE*, same file descriptor?

using fileno() to get the actual file descriptor of stdout.
using fdopen() to create two different FILE* structure, named a and b.
creating two threads, name A and B, using fwrite() to write some contents to a and b.

Question:

Is this operation correct, or recommended?
If A thread is writing 123, B thread is writing 456, is it possible that 142536 got output in the stdout?



Unpredictable and not recommended. 2. Maybe not this exact outcome, but similar ones are possible.


If both threads are writing at the same position (the end of the file), why not use one file stream?  The two threads can use it, and POSIX guarantees that the calls to fwrite() from the two threads will not be interleaved — see POSIX function flockfile()
and its siblings — funlockfile() and ftrylockfile() — all defined on the same page.  Clearly, if the threads try to write 'simultaneously', one will be blocked by the lock while the other writes.

If the threads are writing to different positions in the file, you should use separate file descriptors — or perhaps the POSIX 'positioned write' function pwrite().

Maybe have a look here: fopen and fwrite to the same file from multiple threads
Better define another thread, which is taking control over the file and implement a queue like structure that other tasks can fill with data.
The file thread will then pop (think FIFO) data from the structure and write it to the file.

Currently I am already doing all the logging in a separate thread, however, I can't prevent  other people, or other library, from using stdout directly, so I got this question, is there another way to implement this?

Hmm, I'm not aware how one could prevent the usage of stdout. Just for clarification, with other people/lib you refer to others in the same codebase adding usage of stdout?

Yeah, I guess this have to be done at the documentation part, not the coding part, since the operating system is designed this way.

Yeah I guess this is down to documentation and code review. Maybe someone else has another idea.

Possibly interesting if logging: If a file was opened with open() and mode O_APPEND, then (extract of man open):

O_APPEND: The file is opened in append mode.  Before each write(2),
the file offset is positioned at the end of the file, as if with
lseek(2). The modification of the file offset and the write operation
are performed as a single atomic step.

If using fopen() with mode a or a+, then mode O_APPEND is set.

I guess this behaviour would be platform dependent, and I prefer to limit the context at the standard library scope.

The write might be atomic, but I guess it's only for the buffer. So It might be that you want to write a whole line, but parts of it are written due to buffering. This could then interfere with other write operations, leaving carnage in the file.

Idea behind: If using fdopen() for each new thread, then each thread has its own file. So each thread writes some bytes (less then buffer size) using fwrite(), fprintf() and/or fputs() to the file and closes the action with fflush(), then a atomic append is done.
